# Subclassing CCSprite in COCOS2D v3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, unrecognized-selector

Hi I recently updated to COCOS2D v3 and the code I used to use to subclass a CCSprite no longer works and I am getting an error when I try to assign values to my properties.

```
@interface Alien : CCSprite
{

int _minMoveDuration;
int _maxMoveDuration;
int _hp;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int hp;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int minMoveDuration;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int maxMoveDuration;

@end

@interface SmallFastAlien: Alien
{

}
+(id)alien;
@end
```

Inside the main file I then set my properties for the alien class:

```
#import "Alien.h"

@implementation Alien

@synthesize hp = _hp;
@synthesize minMoveDuration = _minMoveDuration;
@synthesize maxMoveDuration = _maxMoveDuration;

@end

@implementation SmallFastAlien

+ (id)alien
{
SmallFastAlien *alien = nil;
/*if ((alien = [[[super alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"small-1.png"] autorelease]))
{

}*/
alien = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"small-1.png"];

alien.hp = 1;
//alien.minMoveDuration = 3;
//alien.maxMoveDuration = 5;

return alien;
}

@end
```

However, I then get an error when the hp property is set. This did work in v2, but no longer works in v3 and gives the following error:

```
-[CCSprite setHp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a4c5cb0
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a CCSprite, that's why:

```
alien = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"small-1.png"];
```

You ought to be creating an instance of your class, for instance:

```
alien = [SmallFastAlien spriteWithImageNamed:@"small-1.png"];
```

PS: ivar declaration in `@interface` and `@synthesize` in `@implementation` are unnecessary, so is the `assign` keyword (specifically for int and other primitive data types). Xcode auto-synthesizes ivars (with underscore prefix) and getter/setter, assign only affects object (`id`) types. You can shorten your code to:

```
@interface Alien : CCSprite

@property (nonatomic) int hp;
@property (nonatomic) int minMoveDuration;
@property (nonatomic) int maxMoveDuration;

@end


@implementation Alien

@end
```

Comment: Didn't notice I had put CCSprite in there, thanks for the keen eye and thanks for the additional info.